# Where should I set the language (CurrentThread.CurrentCulture)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

In older asp.net - projects we used to set the language usually within the `Application_BeginRequest` - Handler (Global.asax), something like this:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cookie.Lang)
```

Now I am switching to MVC 2 and decided to keep the language as a fix route within the URL. The URL looks like this: `{lang}/{controller}/{action}`

How and where should I read the language from the URL and set the CurrentCulture? How is it best done the MVC - way?

Thx for any tipps!

Comment: This is how I do it: http://www.eworldui.net/blog/post/2008/05/ASPNET-MVC---Localization.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this in global.asax should work

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MvcHandler handler = Context.Handler as MvcHandler;
    if (handler == null)
        return;

    string lang = handler.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["lang"] as string;

    CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(lang);

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
}
```

Comment: I store a user's preferred culture in session state which is first available in this event handler - perfect!